# JQuery dialog not working after first show

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, laravel, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I used JQuery dialog in my project for showing menu of restaurant to user.
also when user sets count of foods its displays the price of order. all of this happening into dialog. so user takes its orders and submit it.order form is in another php file that renders as json and passed to div that contains dialog. everything is good for first time. but if user want to submit another order the nothing works. not ajax not submit form or anything else and user have to reload page to dialog works fine again.
this is my dialog code:

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      width:900,
      height:500,
      hide: function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
      },
      show:  function () {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      },
      open: function() {
        $('#dialog-modal').empty();
        $.ajax('<?php echo url()?>/admin/preload',{
          dataType:'json',
          cache: false,
          success:function(data){
            $('#dialog-modal').html(data.content);
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

the ajax in the open function is loading the menu of restaurant.
this is my submit buttons. there is two submit button.one for submit and close dialog and another for submit and open another dialog for submit.

```
 $('#submit').on('click',function(){
  var data = $('#form').serialize();
  $.post('<?php echo url()?>/admin/add-food',data);
  $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
});
$('#newSubmit').on('click',function(){
  var data = $('#form').serialize();
  $.post('<?php echo url()?>/admin/add-food',data);
  $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
  $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
});
```

**EDIT:**
if i destroy the dialog in the close function its works fine in all circumstances but in the submit and new button its close the dialog and don't open a new dialog box

Comment: i think this line is cause for you issue  `$('#dialog-modal').empty();`

Comment: thanks for your answer but still not working

Comment: are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: "but if user want to submit another order the nothing works. not ajax not submit form or anything else" show us your submit functions, maybe you should just do `$(document).on('click','element',function(){});` because you have got some dynamic buttons

Answer (score 0):

i think, may be your button rendering dynamically.so we need to add event listener to that button.try the below code.

```
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
  var data = $('#form').serialize();
  $.post('<?php echo url()?>/admin/add-food',data);
  $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
});
$(document).on('click','#newSubmit',function(){
  var data = $('#form').serialize();
  $.post('<?php echo url()?>/admin/add-food',data);
  $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
  $('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: do you have any fiddler or site url?